# message queue - smallest amount of work for a consumer

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, rabbitmq, message-queue

This question is about Architecture / Design:

I have a consumer that needs to perform x numbers of tasks, when should I think about breaking the consumer up into smaller task and/or adding the smaller tasks into their own consumer?

Example:

Consumer FooBarShipping does

- adds database entry for reporting
- adds database entry for account
- adds database entry for shipping
- generates shipping invoice ( PDF or other formats if needed )
- creates notification for shipping
- creates notification for account

So my question is, when would I break out the bullet points into smaller consumers? The consumer as is runs fine but I feel it's getting too large and needs to be refactored into smaller, more manageable processes.

Should each bullet point be it's own consumer? I can see breaking them up into three consumers

- database
- pdf ( documents )
- notifications

But what is the smallest unit of work a consumer should do? Do I really need a consumer to run a sql statement?

I watched

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=E708csv4XgY

and to me the consumer looks to do basic tasks which kick off other basic tasks.

Comment: Is this for php/rabbitmq/messagequeue specific question or general design-patterns/architecture?

Comment: Are there any dependnecies in the bullets? I.e. must any bullet be executed before others?

Comment: @Fendy yes it's php/rabbitmq but also general design-patterns/architecture

Comment: @jgauffin the only dependencies are the pdf would need to be created for the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general architecture, you has six modules and each want to be grouped into:

- 1 adds database entry for reporting
- 1 adds database entry for account
- 1 adds database entry for shipping
- 2 generates shipping invoice ( PDF or other formats if needed )
- 3 creates notification for shipping
- 3 creates notification for account

If you implementing repository pattern, the group 1 should be separated into 3 repositories. Each repository handle each entity (reporting, account, shipping); but can provide insert, update, delete and select operation.

Same with group 3, I don't think a general notification object (class in my term) is a good thing because it can grow up to x, y, z entity notification.

But don't worry, you are already at the right path. If I talk about dependency, constructor injection, it is good to separate it to 3 objects. General idea for FooBarShipping ship method:

```
FooBarShipping.Ship(Invoice inv){
    invoiceRepository.InsertNew(inv);
    invoiceGenerator.GenerateInvoice(inv);
    invoiceNotification.Notify(inv);
}
```

And general idea for InvoiceRepository.InsertNew:

```
InvoiceRepository.InsertNew(Invoice inv){
    reportingRepository.InsertNew(inv.Reporting);
    accountRepository.InsertNew(inv.Account);
    shippingRepository.InsertNew(inv.Shipping);
}
```

Same idea with the InvoiceNotification.Notify:

```
InvoiceNotification.Notify(Invoice inv){
    shippingNotification.Notify(inv);
    accoountNotification.Notify(inv);
}
```

It may need adjustment regarding to your data structure and implementation though. But it is the general idea. You can also refer to this [article (Refactoring to Aggregate Services)](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) for references though.